# How to keep div always visible in mobile with user scalable page?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, responsive, viewport

Basically I want to build a page that consists of a weekly calendar. Since the calendar is big I want users to be able to zoom out on it to have an overview and to scroll to the specific hour they want. The problem is that when scrolling the users lose the context of the day they are viewing. Its also important to note that the day is on the left of the page and the scroll is done horizontally.

I built a solution based on window.scrollX that uses a transform to translate the div to the left side of the viewport. This works well in a browser, but unfortunately it doesnt work on mobile. The only way for the translation to be correct is by unzooming the page to maximum on Chrome mobile at least. After trying to debug on Google Chrome responsive design, I see that window.scrollX event holds the value 0 even if the scroll bar is not at the beggining

I would like to know if someone had this problem and have any idea how i should keep a div visible always independently of the zoom and scroll. Note that adding the meta viewport minimum-scale=1 solves the problem but that way I cant unzoom no more.

**EDIT:**

Here's more info of what I'm doing currently. I'm using react and I have a hook (https://github.com/neo/react-use-scroll-position) that does the following:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let requestRunning = null
    function handleScroll () {
      if (isBrowser && requestRunning === null) {
        requestRunning = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          setScrollPosition(getScrollPosition())
          requestRunning = null
        })
      }
    }
    if (isBrowser) {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
      window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleScroll)
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
        window.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleScroll)
      }
    }
  }, [])
```

I have changed the getScrollPosition() function to use document.body.getBoundingClientRect() without success, and the original function uses window.scrollX.

Here's a picture of what I want to achieve in mobile:
[image]

I get that to work, but by limiting the viewport to disable unzoom. But I want the user to be able to unzoom and scroll horizontally while that div is always on the left side of the visible window. Any ideas/alternatives would be really appreciated!

Comment: would you like to post some code?

Comment: Sure I edited my original post! Thank you

Comment: A question, why do you reach for javascript and not css?

Comment: I've tried both position fixed and sticky but they seem to not solve my problem too. The divs are fixed but don't follow the visible window while scrolling.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/pGdjPV shows an example of what I want to achieve, but as you can see on mobile you cant unzoom to get an overview of the calendar, which I would like